# How can I avoid text inside a table from spilling over?

Tags: tables

Here's the code used:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c c}
        \hline
        \textbf{Chave} & \textbf{Valor} & \textbf{Descrição} \\
        \hline
        cables & 6 &  Há seis condutores elétricos nesta linha elétrica.\\
        \hline
        frequency & 50 & Indica que a frequência da linha são 50Hz. \\
        \hline
        power & line & Trata-se de uma linha aérea. \\
        \hline
        source & bing & Fonte de onde a informação foi obtida. Foi usado o \emph{Bing imagery} para preencher as outras tags. \\
        \hline
        voltage & 400000;150000 & Indica que há dois níveis de tensão na linha, um de 400kV e outro de 150kV. \\
        \hline
        wires & double & O número de circuitos trifásicos (três condutores) por linha elétrica. Há dois circuitos trifásicos.  \\
        \hline
       
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{\emph{Tags} da linha de alta tensão \emph{144632829}. Quantas mais \emph{tags} um objeto tiver, mais informação consegue-se extrair desse objeto.}
    \label{tabela_2}
\end{table}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

The text is leaving the page. How can i avoid that?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The entries in the third column might be reformatted as narrower multi-line paragraphs.  That is one of the approaches covered in the answers to this question: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The link that @barbarabeeton has provided in a comment should give you a good overview of the options available to you. To pursue one of these options: I suggest you load the [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package, employ its `tabularx` environment, set the table's target width to `\textwidth`, and use the `X` column type for the third column; line breaking will occur in the 3 final rows. The result of making these changes, which fix the most urgent formatting problem, is shown in the first table below.

In addition, I'd suggest you give the table a more open and inviting "look" by getting rid of most lines drawn with `\hline` and by using the macros of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package for the three remaining three lines; see the code below for an implementation of the idea. Next, do you really need **bold-facing** of the material in the header row? Employing the `\qty` macro (provided by the [siunitx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package) to typeset quantities and associated scientific units would add a nice touch, as would providing for automatic hanging indentation of continuation lines in the third column. The result of making these additional changes is shown in the second table below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % or 'brazilian'?
%\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % optional

\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' column type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
%% 'X' column type with automatic hanging indentation and no 
%% full justification: 
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangindent=1.5em\hangafter=1}X}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for '\qty' macro; see https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]

%% first (minimalist) version: employ a 'tabularx' environment
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c c X}
    \hline
    \textbf{Chave} & \textbf{Valor} & \textbf{Descrição} \\
    \hline
    cables & 6 &  Há seis condutores elétricos nesta linha elétrica.\\
    \hline
    frequency & 50 & Indica que a frequência da linha são 50Hz. \\
    \hline
    power & line & Trata-se de uma linha aérea. \\
    \hline
    source & bing & Fonte de onde a informação foi obtida. Foi usado o \emph{Bing imagery} para preencher as outras tags. \\
    \hline
    voltage & 400000;150000 & Indica que há dois níveis de tensão na linha, um de 400kV e outro de 150kV. \\
    \hline
    wires & double & O número de circuitos trifásicos (três condutores) por linha elétrica. Há dois circuitos trifásicos.  \\
    \hline
   
\end{tabularx}


\bigskip\bigskip
%% second version: apply further tweaks
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l l L @{}}
\toprule
Chave & Valor & Descrição \\
\midrule
cables & 6 &  Há seis condutores elétricos nesta linha elétrica.\\

frequency & 50 & Indica que a frequência da linha são \qty{50}{\hertz}. \\

power & line & Trata-se de uma linha aérea. \\

source & bing & Fonte de onde a informação foi obtida. Foi usado o \emph{Bing imagery} para preencher as outras tags. \\

voltage & 400000;150000 & Indica que há dois níveis de tensão na linha, um de \qty{400}{\kilo\volt} e outro de \qty{150}{\kilo\volt}. \\

wires & double & O número de circuitos trifásicos (três condutores) por linha elétrica. Há dois circuitos trifásicos.  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{\emph{Tags} da linha de alta tensão \emph{144632829}. Quantas mais \emph{tags} um objeto tiver, mais informação consegue-se extrair desse objeto.}
\label{tabela_2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Comment: Two questions about the second version, what does @{} inside of begin do in the second version? And in newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangindent=1.5em\hangafter=1}X}, what does \hangindent=1.5em\hangafter=1}X do?

Comment: @Scipio - The `@{}` particles serve to suppress the whitespace padding that would otherwise be inserted at the left- and right-hand edges of the `tabularx` environment. The  directives `\hangindent=1.5em\hangafter=1` inform LaTeX that the cell contents should be formatted with hanging indentation, starting after line 1, with an indentation amount (from the second line onward) of `1.5em`. (An "em" is a length measure that's traditionally equal to the width of the uppercase letter "M".)